# Error in if else condition TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In a procedure I have statements like below

```
declare @mnth int
select @mnth=month(cast('08/12/2013' as datetime))

if( @mnth<7)
begin

--some statements

end
else
begin

--some other statements

end
```

I am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

I can't understand what is wrong. Please help

Comment: It could be in a statement before else - missing end bracket or something else. I always try to break the `sql` in to smaller portions and execute them separately in order to check the syntax...

Comment: you'll need to post the whole thing

Comment: @MilenPavlov I have removed / commented out all statements from stored proceduere except above..still problem

Comment: What are the `--some statement`? May that's the place you should look for issues.

Comment: @Nilesh Error was becuase I had left else block empty , was planning to write them later ..problem solved now ... THANKS ALL , including downvoter .Lolz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you really entered some statements in between the `begin` and `end` statements? Because I'm pretty sure the error message will vanish once there is something to begin with.
Side note: This probably should have been a comment rather than an answer, but I can't comment yet and I think it will solve the problem (if there really is nothing between the mentioned lines, at least).

Comment: Yes indeed !! it solved irritating and stupid problem .. thanks

Answer (score 3):

There should be some actual code inside begin/end, I guess you only have comments there.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to put a statement into the block.

```
if( @mnth<7)
begin
    select 1
end
else
begin
    select 2
end
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20618)

Comment: Thats it !!! .. Yes I had not written anything in ELSE block as was planning to write statements later

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some statements between `BEGIN` and `END` block , even comments are not allowed .

```
declare @mnth int
    select @mnth=month(cast('08/12/2013' as datetime))

if( @mnth<7)
begin
 DECLARE @Dummy bit 

--some statements



end
else
begin
 DECLARE @Dummy2 bit 
--some other statements

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code

declare @mnth int
select @mnth=month(cast('08/12/2013' as datetime))
BEGIN
if( @mnth<7)
begin

PRINT 'IF'

end
else
begin
PRINT 'else'
end
END